# findViewByID returning null on BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I started using fragments to develop a new app, one of the fragments is a `ListFragment`, 
when I use the adapter I made to show the list's rows I get some `null` from some `findViewById` that I use on the `getView()` method.
The structure is:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

frag_detail.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

detail_list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detailItemLayout" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="txtTitle"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="label1"
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

DetailFragment class

```
public class DetailFragment extends ListFragment {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_detail,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        MonsterDataSource ds = new MonsterDataSource(context);
        List<Monster> lsMonster = ds.getAllMonsters();

        //ListView lsView = (ListView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lsDetail);
        MonsterListAdapter adapter = new MonsterListAdapter(context,lsMonster);
        //lsView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

And the MonsterListAdapter class

```
public class MonsterListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtTitle;
        private ImageView imgIcon;
        private TextView txtHealth;
    }

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Monster> data;
    private ViewHolder holder;

    public MonsterListAdapter(Context c, List<Monster> data){
        context = c;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    /*Basic BaseAdapter Methods*/
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();



            /*Those Guys get null*/
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.detailItemLayout);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);



            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        Monster monster = data.get(i);

        holder.txtTitle.setText(monster.name);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(monster.imgResID);
        holder.txtHealth.setText(monster.health);

        return view;
    }
}
```

In case anyone asking, I'm trying to retrieve the relative layout to add some controls dynamically after.

Thanks

Comment: code looks good. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Are detail_list_item.xml and menu_list_item.xml two different files? Then post the contents of menu_list_item.xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You posted the XML for `detail_list_item.xml` but in your code you inflate `menu_list_item.xml`.

`detail_list_item.xml` contains all of the IDs you are trying to find so it appears you have accidentally inflated the wrong `View` in `getView`

Additionally, you should remove your ViewHolder as a member variable and place it as a local variable in the getView method. You are reusing that variable for multiple views at the same time which means you have the potential for modifying the wrong views at different positions (data going to the wrong positions, etc).

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
 ViewHolder holder;
 ...
 ...//all of your other code here
}
```

Comment: Very nice catch, sir! Thank you I was already banging my head against the wall

Answer (score 0):

Try without affecting "view"

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.detailItemLayout);
    holder.txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
```

*Edit* This works for me... My texviews nbCommentaires and Comment give NullPointerException if i inflate View to them... I thought you get the same issue...

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.comment_row, null);
        }
        v.setTag(position);
        Commentaires o = Global_reco.CommRecos.get(position);
        if (o != null) {    
            TextView nom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nom_com);
            TextView com = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.com);
            ImageView photo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_com);
            TextView nbCommentaires = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nb_commentaires);
            TextView Comment = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nbre_comment);
            photo.setTag(position);
```

Comment: He's in an adapter. findViewById doesn't exist as a method there.